# Move a Three Wheel Omni Robot

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot

I understand this isn't for programming but it's easy to read. I have referenced [This](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7829/how-to-program-a-three-wheel-omni/7833#7833) for a guide on how to move a 3 wheel omni robot but I have encountered a few problems.

```
speed = 100
heading = 45
a1 = 90
a2 = 210
a3 = 330

o1 = a1 - heading
m1 = speed * math.sin(o1)

o2 = a2 - heading
m2 = speed * math.sin(o2)

o3 = a3 - heading
m3 = speed * math.sin(o3)
```

The heading is the angle from X clockwise so 90 being directly up. When I input a heading of 45 it is expected that `m1 = 100, m2 = 0 and m3 = -100` yet I get `m1 = 85, m2 = 100 and m3 = 77` what could be the problem here?

Comment: I believe the motor values should be: `m1 = 70.71, m2 = 25.88, m3 = -96.59`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a degrees/radians issue, but I'm not sure how you're expecting the numbers you've got. Consider your inputs:

```
speed = 100
heading = 45
a1 = 90
o1 = a1 - heading
m1 = speed * math.sin(o1)
```

Then I would expect `o1 = 90 - 45`, or `o1 = 45`, and then I would expect `m1 = 100 * sin(45)`. Here's where it's not clear. Typically I would expect a trig function like sine, cosine, tangent, etc. to take the input in **radians** unless the document explicitly states otherwise.

Let's assume it is in degrees, though. In that case, the sine of 45 degrees is `0.7071`, and so I would expect (in degrees) `m1 = 100 * 0.7071` or `m1 = 70.71`. You stated you're expecting it to be `100`, so I'm not sure where that's coming from.

However, what if the `math.sin` is treating your input as being in *radians*? Well, 45 radians is a TON - multiply by 360 and divide by $2\pi$ to get `45rad = 2578.4deg`. What is the sine of 2,578.4 degrees? 0.852. So, if you're passing in 45 *radians*, then you wind up with `m1 = 100 * 0.852` or `m1 = 85.2`. If you're casting to `int` or something then you wind up with `m1 = 85`, which is what you got.

For `m2`, you're taking `210-45` and then treating that as radians, but `165rad = 9454deg`. Then, sine of 9,454 degrees is 0.998, and you wind up with `m2 = 99.8`, which rounds to `100`.

Try converting to radians first and double-check your expected values and hopefully that gets everything straight for you :)

Comment: I see where I messed up, I got so caught between using X for degrees that it didn't occur to me that 45 degrees wasn't diagonal for a 3 wheel robot. Converting to radians has now given values that are correct so thank you 